# PostGres - Join fields from row type table into columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables, one has a record per row, the other has multiple rows for each records:

**business:**

```
id     name          description       ...
1      Foo Inc.      foo description
2      Bar Inc.      bar description
```

**metrics:**

```
business_id     key     value
1               a       100
1               b       200
1               c       300
1               d       400
...
```

I need a query that will return fields from the business table, plus SOME fields from the metrics table as columns, the result should look like this:

```
id     name        description        property_a     property_c
1      Foo Inc.    foo description    100            300
```

I have something like this, which works but it doesn't seem like a good solution / I'm not sure how it will scale for very large queries:

```
SELECT business.*,
       (SELECT value FROM metrics WHERE business_is = b.id and key = 'a') as property_a,
       (SELECT value FROM metrics WHERE business_is = b.id and key = 'c') as property_c
       ...
FROM business b
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is fine, but I think a lateral join is more appropriate and faster:

```
SELECT b.*, m.*
FROM business b LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT MAX(m.value) FILTER (WHERE m.key = 'a') as property_a,
             MAX(m.value) FILTER (WHERE m.key = 'c') as property_c
      FROM metrics m
      WHERE m.business_is = b.id
     ) m
     ON 1=1;
```